# TypeError: reverse() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

For some weird reason, reverse function is not working even though my url has no arguments.

Url.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/v2/app/nextdialog", views.NextDialog.as_view(), name="app-next-dialog"),
]
```

views.py:

```
class StartAssessment(generics.GenericAPIView):
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        request = build_rp_request(data)
        response = post_to_app_start_assessment(request)
        path = get_path(response)
        step = get_step(response)
        data["path"] = path
        data["step"] = step
        request = build_rp_request(data)
        app_response = post_to_app(request, path)
        message = format_message(app_response)
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

functions.py:

```
def get_endpoint(payload):
    head = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
    url = reverse("app-next-dialog")
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=head)
    return response
```

When I run this I get the following error.

```
url = reverse("app-next-dialog")
TypeError: reverse() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Please does anyone have an idea what's wrong here. I wouldn't think I need to add any other arguments. Thanks

Comment: Where is `reverse()` defined? It's not a built-in, and you don't show an import that seems to provide it.

Comment: A pretty bad typo/auto-complete meant that I had this "from audioop import reverse" instead of "from django.urls import reverse". Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Django `reverse` or DRF `reverse`?

Django reverse returns a relative URI when DRF reverse can return an absolute URI.

Django `reverse` takes 1 argument so this should work

```
url = reverse("app-next-dialog")
```

But DRF `reverse` takes two arguments like:

```
url = reverse("app-next-dialog", request=request)
```

Check your imports

Comment: A pretty bad typo/auto-complete meant that I had this "from audioop import reverse" instead of "from django.urls import reverse". Sorry to waste your time.